# AJAX request doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some PHP script, HTML form and JS code(AJAX):

```
if(isset($_POST['site'])){

$homepage = file_get_contents("http://".$_POST['site']);
preg_match('%<meta.*name="keywords".*content="(.*)"\s+/>%U', $homepage, $regs);

if(count($regs))
{
$myString = implode('', $regs );  
 print_r($myString);
}
}


?>


<form id=payment method="post" name="forma1">
<label for=name>ENTER www.bbc.com:</label>
<input id="name" type=text placeholder="Write here..."         name="site">
<input type="submit" value="START" name="searchbutton" id="sb">
</form>

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#payment').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert("OK, AJAX IS WORKING");
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Without JS code everything works fine. PHP script works also fine and when I click button, after I receive needed information.
But when I try use AJAX and click button, I haven't any action. I think, thant JS code is wrong and may be PHP also too.
Please, experts, who can help me and modify the code?

Comment: have you tried using firebug and see if there are any errors in the console?

Comment: try adding action="" to the form tag

Comment: By the looks of it you are posting to the same script anyway, so you could just use `window.location` instead of `$(this).attr('action')` just to make certain you are getting a correct URL to ajax call.

Comment: @Junior2012 i didn't anything wrong here,but form id you have given is without qutoes..... put them in quotes

Comment: tried to use window.location, but also doesn't works. Also tried to use this.action - and it doesn't works too. Could you check code in your browser?

Comment: Sandeep Kumar thanks, but this is not cause of the problem

Comment: @Junior2012 $(this).attr('action') u have no action in your form?? and first simply put url address in "url" of ajax post and give try

Comment: Sandeep Kumar - I have no action in my form. In my form action=""
You mean full url like this? url: test.php ?

Comment: yes otherwise where want to post this.... action is empty then where this form gonna post?? ... it's imply like a posting a form...you are just doing with ajax... but u have to pass a url ... why u having empty url?\

Comment: either simply put url in ajax aur put in form then use $(this).attr('action') then it can help

Comment: I have action="", because php, js and hmtl code is situated in one file. I tried your variant, change url in ajax, it doesn't work. Could you check it personally? If you have a time of course...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Here's the problem. You're setting `dataType: json`, but your PHP isn't returning JSON. Remove the `dataType: 'json'` line. Also don't forget the opening PHP tag: `<?php`.
EDIT 2: OK, here's the code to get the meta tags and display them. PHP:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents("http://".$_POST['site']);
preg_match('%<meta.*name="keywords".*content="(.*)"\s+/>%U', $homepage, $regs);
if(count($regs)) {
  $myString = implode('', $regs );  
 echo $myString;
}
```

(the code above is yours from your question - I'm assuming it works)
Javascript AJAX success function:

```
success: function (data) {
  $('#metaTags').text(data)
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="metaTags"></div>
```

Comment: Tried to do it, the same result.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use firebug, but in console there are no errors

Comment: I need make the same without reloading page, try to solve this problem about two days and can't. May be somebody can check this code and modify in your web browser? Cause I haven't any variants...

Comment: Tried to remove datatype:'json', but unfortunately it doesn't help.. :/

Comment: Is jQuery being loaded successfully?

Comment: if you mean jquery.js plugin - then yes!

Comment: Have you got some any variants?

Comment: Can you set up an online demo on your website? I'm going to bed soon. Will look more at this tomorrow morning. Thanks!

Comment: To Abraham: here is a link as you wished:
http://tsite.500mb.net/test.php
There is Sandeep Kumar variant. It works, but I need make next: print only php action and print not using alert dialog box. I don't know how to do it. May be you have another idea? Thanks

Comment: OK, so what are you wanting to do with the URL sent from the form?

Comment: Good morning! With url - nothing. I need next: For example I type: www.bbc.com. After clicking on button I need read from this site some content and after print this content, in my example it's meta content tags.(and print it on screen, but not on alert dialog box)...

Comment: Abraham, thanks, first problem was solved. Now my message was printed on my screen(not in alert box). But I need print only meta tags, but there are data + source code like this:  BBC iPlayer, BBCi</div><html>
 
 <head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
 <script type...
and etc...
How to print only meta tags? Is it real or not?

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me...try this way directly put there url like i did
and error response so that if it not works it will show you what kind of error
and remove dataType:'json' too

```
<?php  if(isset($_POST['site'])){

 var_dump($_POST); 
 exit;


}
?>
<html>

<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#payment').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                url: 'test.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert("OK, AJAX IS WORKING"+data);
                },
                 error:   function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status);
                                         } 
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</script>

</head>     

<div>
<form id="payment"    method="post" name="forma1">
        <label for=name>ENTER www.bbc.com:</label>
        <input id="name" type=text placeholder="Write here..."         name="site">
        <input type="submit" value="START" name="searchbutton" id="sb">
</form>

</div>  


</html>
```

Comment: Mm, yes, it's better than my idea, thanks. Tell me please, how make next: to print only php action and do it without alert dialog box? Is it real?

Comment: i didn't understand your question....and if this answer is what your answer looking for then accept it so the others can know question is answered correctly

Comment: Em...when I click on button, I receive the data and the code in alert box. But I need only data(php action) withoud source code. And I need print information without alert box. How to do it? I'm so sorry for my English

Comment: yes it can be done for that u have to make another question i can not answer the whole thing in comment box

Comment: m ok, I can create another question, but why I can't comments in current question?

Comment: u can comment but i can't write answer in comment box..because that will not be readable....and accept answers when it works for u